# Повторяющиеся элементы в массиве

Tags: массивы, objective-c

Помогите решить задачку: программа заполняет массив из десяти элементов случайными числами в диапазоне от 0 до 10, определяет, есть ли среди них повторяющиеся и выводит на экран: да или нет половина решения есть, ниже нужно использовать операторы if/else без сортировки и прочего

```
srand((uint) time(0));

int a[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = rand() % 10;
    NSLog(@"%i", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: что за язык?

Comment: objective c но подойдет и с++

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему надо сделать самую простую хэш-таблицу в которую помещать rand()%10. Функция, добавляющая число в таблицу, просто возвращает признак, это новый элемент или он уже находится в таблице.

Если Вам это сложно, то очевидно надо в цикле по i перед запоминание очередного элемента написать что-то вроде

```
int x = rand()%10;
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    if (a[j] == x) { 
       // уже там
       ....
       break;
    }
a[i] = x;
```

Вот, кто-то преобразовал в ответ.

Сразу как-то я не сообразил, что rand()%10 это *маленькие* числа. Поэтому для решения можно использовать

1. Массив из 10 счетчиков (сначала обнуляем их). Тогда очередное значение x = rand() %10 используем как индекс в этом массиве и увеличиваем счетчик. В конце распечатаем ненулевые счетчики.
2. Или (самое экономное по памяти решение) можно использовать строку бит (v), очевидно помещающуюся для данной задачи в int v = 0;. Установить бит: `v |= (1<<x);` проверить: `(v & (1<<x))`.

В этом случае получается такой код (в принципе массив a[] здесь вообще не нужен)

```
int v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = rand()%10;
    if (v & (1<<x)) {
         // уже есть
         ...
    }
    v |= (1<<x);
}
```

Вообще, в зависимости от того, что точно надо вывести про дубликаты, возможны разные вариации всех этих методов.